# Memory Allocator : avoid free memory twice

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm implementing a memory allocator. I currently meet this issue

```
void deallocate(void* ptr) {
   // code to deallocate memory start at ptr
}

// client test code
printf("Test : deallocate same pointer two times \n");
char* ptr = (char*) allocate(32);
deallocate(ptr);
deallocate(ptr); // ERROR
```

Because deallocate (by anyway), just free memory at pointer ptr. Address stores in ptr still like before, and I cannot set it to NULL (because parameter is a pointer, not a pointer of a pointer).

So my question is : how can I prevent allocated same pointer twice as above scene ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have bookkeeping data with your implementation of `deallocate/alocate`? If so, you could use them to track of freed memory. When `deallocate` is called on already freed memory, print a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent one solution is to track all addresses that have been passed to your version of `free`:  When `free` is called, you first check whether `ptr` has already been passed to you (e.g. by searching for that key in a map/hash table). If it is present, you do nothing; otherwise you an entry for `ptr` into the data structure and proceed to do whatever you need to do.

Of course, it's not quite so simple: you need to also remove the `ptr` from the data structure when you do allocations. If you allocate `size` bytes at address `addr` then you need to remove `ptr` if `addr <= ptr <= addr+size`.

Assuming you're implementing any sort of sensible memory manager however, you will already maintain a free pool (a list of blocks that are either not allocated or were allocated and have been freed) and perhaps even a linked list of allocated blocks.

In which case, you can simply traverse the free pool to see if the block being freed is already listed in the free pool and if so, do nothing. Or, alternatively, iterate the list of allocated blocks and ensure that what you're being asked to free was indeed allocated.

Of course, as someone else already noted, this is typically the responsibility of the caller and not the allocator, although having this sort of functionality in an allocator is useful for debugging purposes.

Comment: I see many memory allocator library on network. does exist any library that implements this feature ? thanks :)

Comment: The standard memory allocator in the C standard library that comes with Windows does when in debug mode. There's UNIX libraries that implement this sort of checking too, but I don't have names off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

Allocators does not prevent this. It's not the responsibility of the allocator, but the allocator user, to care for double deletion.

If you REALLY want your deallocator to have this kind of fool-proof mechanism, you need to store a table of all allocated pointers in a global variable in your allocator implementation. Then the deallocator would first check if the pointer is registered, and if yes, deallocate and remove the pointer from the table. Off course you will need a very efficient container for the table, with low complexity for insertions, deletions, and lookup.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you deallocate memory, NULL the pointer, if you call `free` on NULL pointer, there will be no exception,

Like,

```
deallocate(ptr);
ptr = NULL; 
deallocate(ptr); // NO ERROR
```

Comment: Whether this won't fail really depends on what is happending inside `deallocate()`.

Comment: @alk True. But, function name suggests, it is calling delete. If you call delete twice, error will be sure.

Comment: If it would be `delete` I susopect the OP whould have written `delete`, wouldn't s/he? Also we are talking C here, not C++, aren't we?

Comment: @alk Oh, sorry, then that must be free. You may be right, he might directly right free